# Is it possible to laminate sheets of thin aluminum together with a hot roller press?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

I am researching sheet lamination as an at home additive manufacturing method.  Most papers I have read on the subject show success with ultrasonic welding, uv laser, or adhesive and some sort of post process. I would like to accomplish the same result as ultrasonic welding and laser methods, but use a heated roller press to build  the layers up.

Comment: If it were so easy to 3D print aluminum in this manner it would already be done.

Comment: You *could* clean off the oxide layer using gallium, but the resulting gallium-aluminium alloy is pretty useless. ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlGa

Comment: If the oxidation problem can be worked out, how would I go about understand the conditions for thermo mechanical bonding. Maybe a different metal to start with.  I don't think this an easy problem to solve but easy problems are generally not the ones that need solving.

Comment: Definitely a different metal. Aluminium without its oxide layer is just too reactive: as mentioned in that Wikipedia link, it reacts with water to liberate hydrogen. As niels says, you'd have to work in an oxygen-free and water-free atmosphere. I guess alloys used in soldering could work (with some flux to handle the oxides), but they may be too soft for your purposes. Cadmium would probably work well, but it's also soft, and rather toxic. Maybe the people on the Chemistry stack have better suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this is possible. Aluminum forms a native oxide, which is very stable. Effectively, you would try to bond two oxide surfaces together rather than clean aluminum. You need to add enough energy e.g. in form of temperature or laser irradiation to break up the oxide and allow Al - Al bonds.

I'm not directly working in metallurgy or mechanical engineering, so this is a somewhat speculative answer. I do work with semiconductor materials, including AlAs, where this oxidation is a major problem. That's why I assume it would also be a hurdle for sheet metal.

Answer (score 1):

@Engineer is right. Mechanical bonding of aluminum to aluminum is hard to control because of the oxide interfering with the establishment of good Al-to-Al contact. You would need some means to strip the oxide and then maintain the environment oxygen-free while (for example) friction-welding or thermomechanically bonding the parts together.